# Calling a method inside another method in Angular js factories

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a angularjs factory like this

```
.factory('sampleFactory',function(){
    var self = this;
    return {
        method1: function(arg) {
            console.log(arg);
        },
        method2: function() {
            self.method1('hello');
        }
    }
})
```

When I'm running this code I'm getting an error stating self.method1 is not a function.

How can I make this factory work by calling a method inside another method?

Comment: The object you are returning from factory is different that the one `self` variable is pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.factory('sampleFactory',function(){
    var sampleFactory = {};

    sampleFactory.method1 = function(arg){
        console.log(arg);
    }

    sampleFactory.method2 = function(arg){
         sampleFactory.method1('hello');
    }  

    return sampleFactory;

})
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the `factory recipe` isn't what you need, following what angular suggests probably you need for the `service` recipe: You should use `service` when your service is a *class-like service* because services are instantiated with the `new` operator. So, a better way could be declaring your service in this way:

```js
angular
  .module('test', [])
  .service('sampleFactory', function sampleFactory() {
    
    this.someProperty = 'Hello World';
    this.getSomeProperty = function() { return this.someProperty; };
  
  })
;
```